# Вертикальное меню на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Привет всем!

Мне нужно вот такое [меню](http://greengeckodesign.com/projects/MenuMatic/examples/vertical/index.htm?q=projects/menumatic/examples/vertical/). Проблема в том, что это меню сделано на mootools, а мне нужен jquery, кто-нибудь знает такой скрипт (плагин). Эффект выскальзывания не обязательно.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Могу сказать, что подобное меню можно сделать даже без JS, на чистых CSS/HTML, используя `:hover`.

Посмотрите [сюда](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/). Сделайте подобным образом, сменив ориентацию на горизонтальную/вертикальную. Этот метод более труЪ, и даже более быстрый в плане скорости выполнения. Даже анимацию можно реализовать, используя `css3 animation`.

Answer (score 1):

Да их же [миллионы](http://bit.ly/uu9YQt) в интернете!

Вот похожее на то, что вам нужно ([тыц](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples)). Закладка vertical style.

Comment: `LMGTFU`, да еще и спрятанный за `bit.ly`... Фу!

Comment: Фу - это когда по заголовку вопроса Гугл выдает 25к сайтов, а если его немного правильнее задать, то получаем 10млн результатов, а я вижу его тут. <br/>
Фу - это отправлять новичка читать CSS3, которые официально не утверждены, криво работают в 90% браузеров и имеют сомнительный эффект анимации. Вы бы себе поставили такое меню на сайт?